# Organic Groups "Context"

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, organic-groups

Im using OG and Views. Currently my views have to have a page display to show an event list for each group. So this means that every time a create a group I will have to create another page display in my view for another event list.

So Im wondering if I can just have 1 view with 1 page display that will show a specific event list for a specific group that would be determined through URL.

I beleive this is possible using "arguments" in views but I have no idea how this works.

Comment: Is the view displayed 'inside' the group, or is it listed separately in an "events" area?

Comment: I would like to have it displayed inside the group s only members of that particular group see it but my content type is events...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add arguments, and then put them in the URL.  You could add the "*Organic groups: Groups*" argument, and then make your for you path, enter "events/group/%" (or whatever you want), where the % represents the group's id.  Then when you go to yoursite.com/events/group/15, you'll get the events view for the Organic Group with node id 15.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did manage to get that to work, sort of, the problem is that I can not create a menu item to link to it. Drupal tells me that you cant create a link to a path with a "%" in it... any ideas?